# Mobile project with expo and hapi.js

Tags: api, express, expo, speech-to-text, hapi.js

Im strugglling with an error that im not capable of get a solution and i dont know if its happening in the front or in the back of the app.

Im trying to follow a tutorial where the guy is setting up an app that records your voice and return it as text from Google API speech to text.

this is the front part, the app is failing in the axios.post, the request is not passing and keeps loading until the error log says it cannot connect to the path.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator, Platform,
} from 'react-native'
// import { Audio, Permissions, FileSystem } from 'expo'
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions'
import { Audio } from 'expo-av'
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import axios from 'axios'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#1e88e5',
    paddingVertical: 20,
    width: '90%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 8,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  text: {
    color: '#fff',
  }
})

/*this.recordingSettings = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY = */let recordingOptions = {
  android: {
    extension: '.m4a',
    outputFormat: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG_4,
    audioEncoder: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AAC,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    numberOfChannels: 2,
    bitRate: 128000,
  },
  ios: {
    extension: '.m4a',
    outputFormat: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_IOS_OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG4AAC,
    audioQuality: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_IOS_AUDIO_QUALITY_HIGH,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    numberOfChannels: 2,
    bitRate: 128000,
    linearPCMBitDepth: 16,
    linearPCMIsBigEndian: false,
    linearPCMIsFloat: false,
  },
};

export default class SpeechToTextButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.recording = null
    this.state = {
      isRecording: false,
      //we would like to know if data fetching is in progress
      isFetching: false,
      //we will write the transcript result here
      transcript: '',
    }
  }

  startRecording = async () => {
    // request permissions to record audio
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING)
    // if the user doesn't allow us to do so - return as we can't do anything further :(
    if (status !== 'granted') return
    // when status is granted - setting up our state
    this.setState({ isRecording: true })

    // basic settings before we start recording,
    // you can read more about each of them in expo documentation on Audio
    await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
      allowsRecordingIOS: true,
      interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
      playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
      playThroughEarpieceAndroid: true,
    })
    const recording = new Audio.Recording()
    try {
      // here we pass our recording options
      await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(recordingOptions)
      // and finally start the record
      await recording.startAsync()
      console.log('funcionaaa')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      // we will take a closer look at stopRecording function further in this article
      this.stopRecording()
      console.log('no funca')
    }

    // if recording was successful we store the result in variable, 
    // so we can refer to it from other functions of our component
    this.recording = recording
  }

  stopRecording = async () => {
    // set our state to false, so the UI knows that we've stopped the recording
    this.setState({ isRecording: false })
    try {
      // stop the recording
      await this.recording.stopAndUnloadAsync()
      console.log('aca tiene que parar')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  getTranscription = async () => {
    // set isFetching to true, so the UI knows about it
    this.setState({ isFetching: true })
    try {
      // take the uri of the recorded audio from the file system
      const { uri } = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(this.recording.getURI())
      // now we create formData which will be sent to our backend
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('file', {
        uri,
        // as different audio types are used for android and ios - we should handle it
        type: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'audio/x-wav' : 'audio/m4a',
        name: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `${Date.now()}.wav` : `${Date.now()}.m4a`,
      })
      // post the formData to our backend
      const { data } = await axios.post('http://190.19.68.120/api/speech', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      })
      console.log(data)
      // set transcript from the data which we received from the api
      this.setState({ transcript: data.transcript })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('There was an error reading file', error.request)
      this.stopRecording()
      // we will take a closer look at resetRecording function further down
      this.resetRecording()
    }
    // set isFetching to false so the UI can properly react on that
    this.setState({ isFetching: false })
  }

  deleteRecordingFile = async () => {
    // deleting file
    try {
      const info = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(this.recording.getURI())
      await FileSystem.deleteAsync(info.uri)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('There was an error deleting recorded file', error)
    }
  }

  resetRecording = () => {
    this.deleteRecordingFile()
    this.recording = null
  }

  handleOnPressOut = () => {
    // first we stop the recording
    this.stopRecording()
    console.log('para en el pressout')
    // second we interact with our backend
    this.getTranscription()
  }

  render() {
    const {
      isRecording, transcript, isFetching,
    } = this.state
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPressIn={this.startRecording}
          onPressOut={this.handleOnPressOut}
        >
          {isFetching && <ActivityIndicator color="#ffffff" />}
          {!isFetching &&
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              {isRecording ? 'Recording...' : 'Start recording'}
            </Text>
          }
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>
          {transcript}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Here it is the back part, where i receive the request from the front and send the audio to the google API

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
const fs = require('fs')
const axios = require('axios')
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

const init = async () => {

    const server = Hapi.server({
        port: 3005,
        host: 'localhost'
    });

    server.route({
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/speech',
        config: {
            handler: async (request, h) => {
                const data = request.payload;
                console.log(data)
                if (data.file) {
                    const name = data.file.hapi.filename;
                    const path = __dirname + "/uploads/" + name;
                    const encodedPath = __dirname + "/uploads/encoded_" + name;
                    const file = fs.createWriteStream(path);

                    file.on('error', (err) => console.error(err));

                    data.file.pipe(file);

                    return new Promise(resolve => {
                        data.file.on('end', async (err) => {
                            const ret = {
                                filename: data.name,
                                headers: data.file.hapi.headers
                            }

                            ffmpeg()
                                .input(path)
                                .outputOptions([
                                    '-f s16le',
                                    '-acodec pcm_s16le',
                                    '-vn',
                                    '-ac 1',
                                    '-ar 41k',
                                    '-map_metadata -1'
                                ])
                                .save(encodedPath)
                                .on('end', async () => {
                                    const savedFile = fs.readFileSync(encodedPath)

                                    const audioBytes = savedFile.toString('base64');
                                    const audio = {
                                        content: audioBytes,
                                    }
                                    const sttConfig = {
                                        enableAutomaticPunctuation: false,
                                        encoding: "LINEAR16",
                                        sampleRateHertz: 41000,
                                        languageCode: "en-US",
                                        model: "default"
                                    }

                                    const request = {
                                        audio: audio,
                                        config: sttConfig,
                                    }

                                    const [response] = await client.recognize(request);
                                    const transcription = response.results
                                        .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
                                        .join('\n');

                                    fs.unlinkSync(path)
                                    fs.unlinkSync(encodedPath)
                                    resolve(JSON.stringify({ ...ret, transcript: transcription }))

                                })
                        })
                    })
                }
            },
            payload: {
                output: 'stream',
                parse: true,
            }
        }
    })

    await server.start();
    console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

init();
```

i thought i could try migrating the server to express.js but under handler, i got payload key, and i dont know what to do with that in an express server.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: did you ever figure this out?